# what will be the time complexity of below recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recursion

Please help me find the time-complexity of below recursive algo. I have guessed for first two return statements.Please correct me if I am wrong. But I can't find time-complexity of third return statement because it will loop till we get a factorial of NUM contining 0 and 7.

```
    public class Check
   {

   static long NUM = 11;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

       System.out.print(find007(NUM));
   }

     static long find007(long n){

       if(is007(n))  //O(1)
         return n;

       if(n+NUM<n)   //O(1)
         return 0;

       return find007(n+NUM);  //O(?)
     }
     static boolean is007(long n){
        while(n!=0 && (n%10==0 || n%10==7))  //O(log n)
         n=n/10;

       return n==0;
     }
}
```

Pseudo-code:

```
static long find007(long n){

 check if number or its multiple consists of only 0 or 7.
if yes, return the answer/number
 return n;

//if not, keep checking for the other multiples of NUM
i.e n+NUM (here NUM=11, so it will keep adding 11 to itself till 77)
   return find007(n+NUM);
}

 static boolean is007(long n){

   continue till n!=0 and  n%10==0 OR n%10==7
        n=n/10;

     return true if n==0;         

         }
```

Comment: @DavidRicherby : Thank you for sharing the link. But it involves tough mathematics and I am a non-CS grad and newbie to algorthms. Maybe you could explain in simpler language. I know the master-theorem but unable to apply it here.

Comment: Can you replace the C++/Java code with pseudocode?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: edited the question and added the pseudocode. Hope it is understandable

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Algorithms analysis without mathematics is like structural analysis without mathematics: ultimately impossible. You will either have to learn some amount of mathematics (not *much* more than high-school level, in my estimation) or resort to other means of estimating your code's performance.

Comment: Thank you @Raphael for your valuable suggestions. I will keep that in mind next time before asking question here

Comment: @Raphael: I will explain you where I am stuck in this question. Suppose if here in the recursion the return statement was `return fun(n-1)` then the complexity would be O(n) as function will execute n times or if it was `return fun(n-5)` then also it will execute O(n-5)~O(n). But here we do not know when it will find the multiple of the number which contains just 0 or 7, so how many times will it execute?  Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ankita "it will execute O(n-5)" -- wrong. It seems you are lacking basic skills in solving recurrences (which has nothing to do with algorithm analysis per se); our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers) may help.

Comment: In `return find007(n+NUM);` ,we don't know when we will find the required multiple

Comment: @Raphael: Thanks again for help. O(n-5) will be a tail-recursive as it goes from n to 0. And the `return find007(n+NUM);` will be of the type T(n)=T(n−1)+f(n), where f(n) is monotone increasing as n+NUM is increasing. Please correct me if I am wrong